# jFrame Exiting when a value is achieved

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am looking to close a jFrame window when a certain value is achieved, namely 100. The frame is simply a progress bar, displayed to demonstrate how far calculations are. How can I exit when percent = 100? I have my code below.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PicCalc 
{
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  long i = 0;
  int x = 0;
  int itinerations = 1;
  int percent = 100/itinerations;

  System.out.println("How many itinerations?");
  itinerations = keyboard.nextInt();

  for(i = 0; i <= itinerations; i++)
  {
     x = x + 5; //Will be replaced with more complicated stuff later

  }


  JFrame f = new JFrame("Loading...");
  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  Container content = f.getContentPane();
  JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
  progressBar.setValue(percent);
  progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
  Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Calcualating...");
  progressBar.setBorder(border);
  content.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  f.setSize(300, 100);
  f.setVisible(true);

 System.out.println(x);


}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for an example because your current code structure will not support your requirement. That is you continually need to update the progress bar value so you need some kind of loop for this.

Also, I doubt you should be using a JFrame. Typically you would use a popup JDialog from your main application. Once your task is finished then see Nizil's suggestion to close the dialog.

Comment: Thanks, I think the Swing tutorial made things much easier!

Answer (score 1):

You probably can use [`java.awt.Window#dispose()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29)

Comment: Although being a good tip this doesn't completely answer the question: *jFrame Exiting* ***when a value is achieved***

Answer (score -1):

here's the simple process:

```
if(progressbar.getValue==100){  
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all: ***jFrame*** *Exiting when a value is achieved*. `System.exit(0)` finishes the `JVM` execution returning `0` (it means successfuly) even when a ton of errors may happened. This is the worst way to finish a program execution.

Comment: sorry I thought he wanted to close the program :3
use frame.dispose() then :)